# bootstrap typeahead from a loop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I currently get a list of cities from a loop that looks like this:

```
<label>City</label>
<select class="input-block-level" name="city">
     <option value=" ">Any</option>
     <!-- TMPL_LOOP Cities -->
     <option value="<!-- TMPL_VAR city_name -->">
     <!-- TMPL_VAR city_name -->
     </option>
     <!-- /TMPL_LOOP -->
</select>'
```

How would i convert this into a typeahead? I do not have the ability to change the loop code, so i have to work with what i have.

I tried this and did not work:

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="typeahead" type="text" 
data-provide="typehead"
data-items="4"
data-source="[
<!-- TMPL_LOOP Cities -->
"<!-- TMPL_VAR city_name -->",
<!-- /TMPL_LOOP -->
]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have some issues with your quotes. Try this syntax (notice the single quotes):

```
<input data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" data-source='["purple", "monkey", "dishwasher"]' />
```

Also, you will want to make sure you don't have any trailing commas in your array (i.e. `["a", "b", "c",]`), as this will break IE.

**Update/Alternative Solution**

Another approach would be to use javascript:

```
var src = [
    <!-- TMPL_LOOP Cities -->
    "<!-- TMPL_VAR city_name -->",
    <!-- /TMPL_LOOP -->
];

$('#myTypeahead').typeahead({
    source: src,
    items: 4
});

<input id="myTypeahead" type="text"/>
```

Comment: it looks like the loops will not function in an attribute like this. i may have to look at invoking it via javascript